# Python: Regex Search

Tags: python, regex, delimiter

I wanted to split a sentence on multiple delimiters:

.?!\n

However, I want to keep the comma along with the word.
For example for the string

```
'Hi, How are you?'
```

I want the result

```
['Hi,', 'How', 'are', 'you', '?']
```

I tried the following, but not getting the required result

```
words = re.findall(r"\w+|\W+", text)
```

Comment: I think the clue might be in your question - try using `re.split`, e.g. `re.split(r'\s+', text)`?

Comment: Are you looking to keep only commas attached to each word? What is your criteria for punctuation? When do you split and when do you not?

Comment: If you want to keep the coma, maybe you can try this: re.findall(r"\w+[,]*", t)

Comment: I want to split the sentence on occurrence of white spaces. Since a comma is attached is attached to the word hi, it should be displayed along with hi.

However delimiters like "." "!" "?" "newline" which occur at the end of the sentence should be treated as a word and splitted

Comment: that information should be in your question

Comment: words = re.split(r'\s+', text) gives the following as the output:

['hi,', 'how', 'are', 'you?']

It doesn't split the "?" at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`re.split` and keep your delimiters, then filter out the strings which only contain whitespace.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Hi, How are you?'
>>> [x for x in re.split('(\s|!|\.|\?|\n)', s) if x.strip()]
['Hi,', 'How', 'are', 'you', '?']
```

Answer (score 2):

If using re.findall:

```
>>> ss = """
... Hi, How are
...
... yo.u
... do!ing?
... """
>>> [ w for w in re.findall('(\w+\,?|[.?!]?)?\s*', ss) if w ]
['Hi,', 'How', 'are', 'yo', '.', 'u', 'do', '!', 'ing', '?']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
re.findall('(.*?)([\s\.\?!\n])', text)
```

With a bit of itertools magic and list comprehensions:

```
[i.strip() for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(re.findall('(.*?)([\s\.\?!\n])', text)) if i.strip()]
```

And a bit more comprehensible version:

```
words = []
found = itertools.chain.from_iterable(re.findall('(.*?)([\s\.\?!\n])', text)
for i in found:
    w = i.strip()
    if w:
        words.append(w)
```

Comment: With re.findall('(.*?)([\s\.\?!\n])', text), I get the following output:

[('hi,', ' '), ('how', ' '), ('are', ' '), ('you', '?')]

Comment: Yes, you have to filter the output next, but see timgeb's answer for much nicer version.